# How to format Ceph S3 bucket-policy Principal?

Tags: amazon-s3, access-control, ceph, identity-management

I'm trying to set the bucket policy for a Ceph S3 bucket.

This policy works but enables public access

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllForAuthenticatedUsers",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I believe I need to specify each user who has access to the bucket in `Principal`. The [Ceph docs here](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/bucketpolicy/) show this example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::usfolks:user/fred:subuser"]},
    "Action": "s3:PutObjectAcl",
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:s3:::happybucket/*"
    ]
  }]
}
```

I believe `usfolks` in the example is the tenant, the docs make this mention:

> We use the RGW ‘tenant’ identifier in place of the Amazon twelve-digit account ID. In the future, we may allow you to assign an account ID to a tenant, but for now, if you want to use policies between AWS S3 and RGW S3 you will have to use the Amazon account ID as the tenant ID when creating users.

I checked that the `tenant` on my bucket is an empty string, verified using `radosgw-admin bucket stats`. Also `subsers` are not set when looking at `radosgw-admin user info`: `"subusers": [],`.

Here are some of the many formats I've tried for `Principal`, in each case I tested by attempting to download a file and I got an error `403 HeadObject operation Forbidden`:

```
"AWS": ["myuser-000"]
"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam:::user/myuser-000:"]
"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam:::user/*"]
"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::usfolks:user/myuser-000:"]
"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam:::myuser-000:"]
```

In these cases `myuser-000` is also the bucket owner, I'm using this user's credentials for authentication.

Comment: you installed ceph somethere, right? like EC2? EC2 has a IAM role attached. Put the iam role as the principle to the S3 bucket resource policy. Another way is to add required S3 actions to the iam role of the EC2 directly.

Comment: This is a standalone Ceph installation, not hosted on AWS. I have access to `radosgw-admin` to manage the Ceph installation. Our Ceph instance runs under a Kubernetes cluster that we manage. Since there's no EC2 or IAM, the structure is purely managed by ceph within `radosgw-admin` but the Ceph docs aren't specific enough for me to follow this detail.

Comment: The easiest way is to a create an user with a specific IAM role which allows access to the S3. The user can have an access key. The access key can be passed via k8s secret to your ceph installation.

Comment: Ah, you mean in radosgw-admin I need to create a role and define permissions at that level (https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/role/), not in the bucket policy the way I'm trying to do it?

Comment: if you want the bucket to be private, then you need to have an AWS Role to access it. In fact there many ways how to do it. I advise you consult someone to make it secure enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the bucket policy that finally worked:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam:::user/USERNAMEA",
          "arn:aws:iam:::user/USERNAMEB",
          "arn:aws:iam:::user/USERNAMEC"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME",
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This assumes a default Ceph environment not using tenants. Replace `BUCKETNAME` and `USERNAME#`

There is a default deny for principal's not matching the list of users in this policy doc.

Notably wildcards `*` in the principals didn't work in Ceph.